# TypeError: $(...).error is not a function

Tags: jquery

Tenho um código que apresenta erro na versão mais recente do jQuery v3.1.1
Na versão 1 não dá erro.
Eis o código:

```
//IMAGE ERROR
$('img').error(function () {
    var s, w, h;
    s = $(this).attr('src');
    w = s.split('&')[1].replace('w=', '');
    h = s.split('&')[2].replace('h=', '');

    $(this).attr('src', '../tim.php?src=admin/_img/no_image.jpg&w=' + w + "&h=" + h);
});
```

A documentação do erro:
[documentação aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Olhe a documentação do jQuery, que diz:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .error() method is deprecated. Use .on( "error", handler ) to attach event handlers to the error event instead.

Ou seja, o jeito que está chamando, está obsoleta. Mais informações no site do [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/error/).

Answer (score 3):

Troque isso:

```
$('img').error(function () {

});
```

Por isso:

```
$('img').on('error', function () {

});
```